# Issue with Pandas and circular reference in import

Tags: python, pandas, importerror

I am trying to use pandas for the first time and I have copied a very simple program

```
import pandas as pd
series1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
print(series1)
```

The issue I am having is that when I try and run the program I am getting the following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\faintr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\faintr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\pandas.py", line 2, in <module>
    series1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Series' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Pandas version(1.14.0) is installed.

I have looked into circular imports and whilst I think I understand the concept if this is the cause I do not know how to fix it. I have tried downgrading pandas to an earlier version with no look

Can anyone help please

Comment: What is your filename ? Is that `pandas.py` we see in stacktrace, if yes that''s the problem

Comment: out of curiosity, is panda up to 1.14? last time i checked it was 1.03

Comment: @sammywemmy yes pandas version is still 1.03. OP must have mixed this up.

Comment: @azro - thanks . I had named file pandas - renamed file and all is now okay